# How to resolve conflicts of merge --squash via command line of a protected branch?

Tags: git, git-merge, conflict, squash

**I am trying to merge --squash a feature branch to master (which is protected and cannot be pushed to),**
and there are conflicts. So the auto-merge is failing and I get a message that it should be done by the command line with some instructions:

1. fetch both
2. checkout the protected branch (master)
3. run the merge command
4. resolve conflicts
5. **push to the protected branch (master)**
   This of course is failing because I can't push to the protected branch. And so I am left with conflicts and unable to merge the branch.

**Is there a correct way to merge --squash a branch into a protected one?**
How can I resolve these conflicts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means your branch is behind the master branch and master moved ahead and there could be changes in the same file/same line which git can't resolve automatically. You can rebase it onto the master first, resolve conflicts if any and push your branch to remote.

```
git fetch origin
git checkout master
git pull origin master
git checkout <your branch>
git rebase master
git push --force origin <your branch>
```

Now your branch will be up to to date with master and then you do what you were doing earlier.

Comment: Thabk you. You are awsome